# Moving Data From one Table to Another Similar Table

Tags: java, sql, servlets, db2

I usually try to avoid using cursors and looping through a result set but how can I accomplish this in the following scenario without looping through `SomeTable` and inserting rows one by one to `MyTable`?

Simple schema is as follows:

```
MyTable
- Name  VARCHAR(20)
- Code1 CHAR(5)
- Code2 CHAR(5)

SomeTable
- Name      VARCHAR(20)
- SomeCode1 CHAR(10)
- SomeCode2 CHAR(10)
```

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Code1, Code2)
SELECT Name, First Five Chars of SomeCode1 Only if SomeCode2 is not null or empty or doesn't have a certain value, SomeCode2
FROM SomeTable
```

I'm doing this inside Java code but I'm not sure if it's possible to do this in one whole `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement. I'm almost close to writing a for loop with single `INSERT` statements in them. Should I create some sort of a function in the database or.. ? I'm using DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, Code1, Code2)
SELECT Name, 
  CASE When coalesce(SomeCode2, '')='' Then NULL
       When SomeCode2=@somevalue Then NULL
       Else substring(SomeCode1, 1, 5)
, SomeCode2
FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be SUBSTR() instead of SUBSTRING() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into MyTable (Name, Code1, Code2)
select Name, case when (SomeCode2 is not null and length(trim(SomeCode2)) <> 0) then substr(SomeCode1, 0, 5) end, SomeCode2 from SomeTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want null entries when not found:

```
insert into MyTable (Name, Code1, Code2)
select
  Name,
  if(not isnull(SomeCode2) and SomeCode2 != ''
     and SomeCode2 != 'foo', substring(SomeCode1,1,5), null),
  SomeCode2
  from SomeTable
;
```

-or-

If you don't want any row to exist when entries aren't found:

```
insert into MyTable (Name, Code1, Code2)
select
  Name,
  substring(SomeCode1, 1, 5),
  SomeCode2
  from SomeTable
  where not isnull(SomeCode2) and SomeCode2 != '' and SomeCode2 != 'foo'
;
```